# My react frontend mentor challenge solution wont deploy to github

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to deploy and build my react project to github, but when I run gh-pages -d deploy. i keep getting the error

gh-pages : The term 'gh-pages' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- gh-pages -d build
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gh-pages:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException.
  ```

I have tried npm run build which comes back as successful and the build folder is ready to be deployed.
I have installed npm i gh-pages@latest and still get the error.
I have followed the link to https://cra.link/deployment.
When I follow the github website link, it shows a blank page even though the files are uploaded to my github repository. https://saram7619.github.io/advice-generator-app/

```
{
  "name": "advice",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/saram7619/advice-generator-app/",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

How do I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try `npm run deploy`?

Comment: I've tried npm run reploy a few times. Its successful. The issue is with the gh-pages -d build.